# MQL - checking whether a topic has an associated image

Tags: php, freebase, mql

I am using the Freebase Image Service 
eg.

[Image of Arnie](https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/m/0tc7)

However, many of the topics don't have images
eg.

[Lord Voldemort](https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/m/0c8lv)

How do I check the topic using MQL (and PHP) to see whether it has an associated image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `/common/topic/image` property - for example,

```
{
  "id": "/en/snow_leopard",
  "/common/topic/image": [{
    "id":   null,
    "name": null
  }]
}​
```

[Query editor link](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%7B%22id%22%3A%22%2Fen%2Fsnow_leopard%22%2C%22%2Fcommon%2Ftopic%2Fimage%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22name%22%3Anull%7D%5D%7D) - wrapping that into PHP should be easy.